# Cassandra error: ERROR 16:27:50 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting gossip state mutation from illegal thread: GossipTasks:1

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes

After cloning Cassandra database from one cluster to another cluster using nodetool refresh we are seeing below errors often. This might not be related to migration but not sure. What causes this issue? Is there any explanation? How to fix this and does this cause any issues?

```
ERROR 16:27:50 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting gossip state mutation from illegal thread: GossipTasks:1
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.checkProperThreadForStateMutation(Gossiper.java:178)
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.evictFromMembership(Gossiper.java:465)
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doStatusCheck(Gossiper.java:895)
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.access$700(Gossiper.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper$GossipTask.run(Gossiper.java:240)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$UncomplainingRunnable.run(DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:118)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:84)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting gossip state mutation from illegal thread: GossipTasks:1
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.checkProperThreadForStateMutation(Gossiper.java:178) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.evictFromMembership(Gossiper.java:465) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doStatusCheck(Gossiper.java:895) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.access$700(Gossiper.java:78) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper$GossipTask.run(Gossiper.java:240) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$UncomplainingRunnable.run(DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:118) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:84) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
```